# Hung Up on Concatenation Code

Tags: sql, concatenation, error-code, mysql-error-1054

I am trying to combine two tables, `S&P2` and `Foundation`, so that I can transfer information from corresponding rows in `S&P2.Tic` into `Foundation.Ticker`.

I created this code; however, no matter how I alter the code SQL always returns the Error Code 1054: Unknown Column/Field. This field is always `S&P2`. If this error does not pop up, SQL will just continually run.

```
USE nasdaqProj;

SELECT `S&P2`.`﻿fyear`
FROM `nasdaqProj`.`S&P2`;

select * from Foundation;

SELECT `S&P2`.`conm` As sconm, `S&P2`.`tic` as 'ticker'
from nasdaqProj.`S&P2`
left outer join Foundation
ON `S&P2`.conm LIKE CONCAT (Foundation.comnm,'%')
and `S&P2`.fyear = Foundation.year

UNION

SELECT `S&P2`.`conm` As sconm, `S&P2`.`tic` as ticker

from nasdaqProj.`S&P2`
right outer join Foundation
ON `S&P2`.conm LIKE CONCAT (Foundation.comnm,'%')
and `S&P2`.fyear = Foundation.year;
```

I have been stuck on this for a while, and after reading the other error code 1054 question answers I was still unable to apply the solutions to my code.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried breaking the query into as small statements as possible? Try running each side of the union statement separately.

Comment: That will run, but it only returns `Foundation` and `S&P2` columns separately; however, I need to combine the `S&P2` tickers with the `Foundation` comnm.

Comment: So both sides of the union will run separately? Maybe try wrapping each side of the union in parentheses.

Comment: Also, the second half of the union statement will probably need to be updated so that the fields selected are from the Foundation table as S&P2 will be null.